# Display Data from SQLite in Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm not that good in programming and I need your help guys. I only able to display the data in textview. It only shows the last data in database SQLite.

This is my databasehelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.jathniel.myapplication/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "example.sqlite";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private Context myContext = null;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = this.checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            this.copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            throw new Error("Error");
        }
    }

}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = this.myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    FileOutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int length;
    while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String e = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(e, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)null, 0);
    } catch (SQLiteException var3) {
        ;
    }

    if(checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null;
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    this.myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)null, 0);
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if(this.myDataBase != null) {
        this.myDataBase.close();
    }

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public void createDatabase() {
}
```

this is the dataDB

```
public class DataDB {
DatabaseHelper con;
String name,lastname;

public DataDB() {
}

public String getNameDB(Context context) throws SQLException {
    this.con = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    try {
        this.con.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException var4) {
        ;
    }

    if (!this.con.checkDataBase()) {
        return "ERROR";
    } else {
        this.con.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.con.getWritableDatabase();

        for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM exampleTable", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.name = cursor.getString(0)) {

        }

        this.con.close();
        return this.name;


    }

}
public String getLNameDB(Context context) throws SQLException {
    this.con = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    try {
        this.con.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException var4) {
        ;
    }

    if(!this.con.checkDataBase()) {
        return "ERROR";
    } else {
        this.con.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.con.getWritableDatabase();

        for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT lastname FROM exampleTable", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.lastname = cursor.getString(0)) {

        }


        this.con.close();
        return this.lastname;
    }
    }
```

I have a main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DataDB data = new DataDB();
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

public MainActivity() {
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, name);



     try {
           listAdapter.add(data.getNameDB(this));
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change

```
this.name = cursor.getString(0)
```

to

```
this.name += cursor.getString(0)
```

If you want to display all name from database in ListView, follow [this tutorial](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php).
As you can see in the tutorial, you need to create an array name like this

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList();
```

instead of `String name;`

For add the data to array list:

```
for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT lastname FROM exampleTable", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.name.add(cursor.getString(0))) {
```

Hope this help

Comment: how to display it via listview?i got error when i tried to convert textview into listview

Comment: yeah but first i use listview and i got error so i used textview only

Comment: yes and when i apply your comment it shows all the names. now i want to convert it into listview.

Comment: what will be the code in putting the data in arraylist?

Comment: still not displaying in listview

Comment: Could you update your post with all new source code so I can easy for check. Thank you

Comment: nice. i have not tested it. please mark this answer is correct if possible. thank you

Comment: if i will display also the lastname,i will create another listview or is it possible in one listview?

Comment: Of course, you can make it in one listview but you need to do with another way by create your own adapter (it is popular way now)
I'm strong recommend you learn through [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92 )
This will help you to do all things with listview